# Redis cluster ready client

Tags: windows, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

Recently I started learning Redis and have been able to do everything from learning aspect in 32 bit Windows. I am a .net developer and made caching available using Redis using [ServiceStack client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) in a Web API setup. I have been able to successfully run a Redis cluster of 4 masters and 4 slaves, and was wondering how can I make that work in conjunction with the ServiceStack client.

My main concern is that if the master that I connect my client to, goes down, then how can the client automatically connect to some other available slave that takes over, as the port of that slave is going to be different. So failover is working at Redis level, but how the client handles it?

I recreated the mentioned scenario, using Redis Command Line Interface, but when I took the master down, the interface just stopped responding, as in everything was just going in a blackhole. So, per my experience, the cli does not automatically handles failover as a client.

I have started studying [StackExchange's client](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) to Redis, but still have the same question.

I am using Redis distribution given by Microsoft for learning purposes available at Github (Sorry, cannot provide link as I am new here and do not have sufficient reputation points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) are additional Redis processes which monitor the health of your Redis Master/Slaves and takes care of performing Automatic Failover when it detects that your Master instance is down. The [Redis Config project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config) provides a quick way to setup a popular Redis Sentinel Configuration.

The [ServiceStack.Redis Client supports Redis Sentinel](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-sentinel) and implements the [Recommended client Strategy](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel-clients) which is what enables it to automatically recover after a failover by asking one of the Sentinels for the next available address to connect to, resuming operations with one of the available instances.

You can learn more about [Redis Sentinel in the official Documentation](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel).

Comment: Thanks mythz for the answer. May be that my understanding is green at the moment, but because I am aiming to use Redis Cluster, I believe that I should not be using Redis Sentinel setup. I do want to leverage the automatic sharding and replication capabilities that we get out of the box in Redis Cluster. Please pardon me if I am wrong in my understanding. I used the link to read up on cluster vs sentinel: https://fnordig.de/2015/06/01/redis-sentinel-and-redis-cluster/

Comment: @Tux if you need sharding you'll want to use Redis Cluster, Redis Sentinel provides monitoring, auto failover and uses replication already built into Redis. ServiceStack doesn't support cluster so you'll need to use StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: @Tux also note that ServiceStack.Redis is a commercially-supported product with limitations for free use (See [free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas)).

Comment: Thanks thepirat000. That is definitely helpful. I didn't knew that. Ultimately all the knowledge about Redis will be utilized in a commercial environment in my case.